# Newer support library on older device

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am just confused about the versioning behaviour of support library

Let's say you target SDK 28 and your support library is of version 28 . Now obviously there are new features introduced in Version 28 of support library

Now let's say a device running android SDK 25. Will it see the nee changes in support library 28 .

For example, if you disable labels on bottom navigation view (which is introduced in support 28), will device running SDK 25 disable the labels as well?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

support libraries are safest libraries in android, so if you use version 28, if the feature could be available in API 25 it will work, if it's not it would not work. but most of the time support libraries are there to support everything on any device.

when you use support library v7, it means everything in that library can work on all Api versions down to API 7:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
```

now the support libraries has 3 version: v4 and v7 and v13.
there's no difference between them, when it comes to functionality. it only means that the v13 is supported down to API version 13 and v4 is supported all the way down to API version 4.

Comment: Not agree regarding library v7. Google recognized that  they started to add all the latest changes to this library. And the 28.0.0 is the latest one. Now they will use new AndroidX libraries. And if system doesn't support any method, AS will let you know, that min. version for this one and your min version is anotherone

Comment: What about the android design support library? It is not v7, v4, or v13.

Comment: yes, design is the only support library that does not have any version number, but according to Fragmented podcast, it is v7.

Answer (score 0):

> Now let's say a device running android SDK 25. Will it see the nee
>   changes in support library 28

Yes, that's the main goal of the Support Library / AndroidX. Other uses are Convenience, Helper Classes, Debugging and Utilities ([source](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/#uses)).